# SSL is dead slow in Internet Explorer + Safari

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, https, internet-explorer

- I had a Comodo SSL certificate installed on my website yesterday, after going through a lot of trouble it has finally been activated.
- I am, however, experiencing serious issues in Safari and Internet Explorer 7: page loads are dead slow, and most of the times the pages are only loaded partially - often they arent loaded at all. Chrome and FF show no delay.
- Additionally, Firefox 8 won't accept the certificate - however that's a marginal issue, the website targets a very specific audience, with 99% Internet Explorer visitors.
- I don't have access to the webserver itself, I have to rely on the support theme - and my current contact doesn't seem very competent. It should be fixed by tomorrow however, since the website will get an external security audit on Monday.
- The website contains one static HTML that can be used for testing: https://axa.tfo.be/incentives/cipres/static.html

**My question:**

- Any ideas what might be the problem, so I can point support in the right direction?

Comment: Please do not cross-post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466088/ssl-is-dead-slow-in-internet-explorer-safari and http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/23240/ssl-is-dead-slow-in-internet-explorer-safari). However I think that this is the correct place to post it.

Comment: @MarkHenderson I'm sorry, I realize this goes against StackExchange policy - but I'm really desperate for an answer. It's a very important customer, and they have planned a security audit tomorrow. Thanks for not closing the question.

Comment: Do you see the same issue over non-ssl traffic? Also, do you repeatedly see the same issue? I saw what you describe the first time I loaded the page, but subsequent refreshes seem to be OK.

Comment: @MarkHenderson no, non ssl traffic goes fine, no delay at all. Subsequent refreshes in IE show the same delay, however. Still no response from webhost support...

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on this as I can't reproduce it every time, but it looked like it was taking forever because of the OCSP check. Can you purchase another $5 certificate from somewhere else to try another one? I've used cheapssls.com in the past.